# Using ifelse function for two matching strings/words

Tags: r, if-statement

My question is simple. I've a dataset like this one:

```
     observed predicted probability result2
1     Head-up   Grazing   0.2727273   FALSE
2     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727    TRUE
3     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727    TRUE
4     Head-up   Grazing   0.5454545    TRUE
5     Head-up   Grazing   0.7272727    TRUE
6     Head-up   Grazing   0.4545455   FALSE
7     Head-up Vigilance   0.3636364   FALSE
8     Head-up   Grazing   0.3636364   FALSE
9     Head-up Vigilance   0.3636364   FALSE
10    Unknown   Grazing   0.3636364   FALSE
11     Moving   Head-up   0.4545455   FALSE
12     Moving   Head-up   0.3636364   FALSE
```

Where I've successfully created column `results2` by using the `ifelse` function like so:

```
table$result1<-ifelse(table$probability>0.5,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

However, I'm trying to use the same function to create column `result1`, which would be:

```
table$result1<-ifelse(table$observed=table$predicted, "POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE")`.
```

I'm getting the error `Error: unexpected '='` in `table$result1<-ifelse(table$observed=`

Indeed, I'd like to have "POSITIVE" if the word on column `observed` matches the one on the column `predicted` of the same row, and "NEGATIVE" if vice versa..

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need `==` to compare. `=` is assigning (same as `<-`). Also, the first `ifelse` is not necessary. Just `... > 0.5` will result to a boolean

Comment: and `table` is a common base function, better to avoid it as a variable name

Comment: Yes, even when using `==` I get `> table$result1<-ifelse(table$observed==table$predicted, "POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE")
Error in Ops.factor(table$observed, table$predicted) : 
  level sets of factors are different`

Comment: Yes, but you get a different error. This time your two variables are factors with different levels, thus cannot be compared. Convert to `as.character` first and try again

Comment: Could you help me when using `as.character` ? I've tried `as.character(table)` , `as.character(table$observed)
as.character(table$predicted)` and still get `> table$result1<-ifelse(table$observed==table$predicted, "POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE")
Error in Ops.factor(table$observed, table$predicted) : 
  level sets of factors are different`

Comment: maybe you juste want to try `confusionMatrix` from `caret` package and just use `confusionMatrix(table$observed, table$predicted)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Sotos commented (sorry I hijacked your commented, but the correct answer was not yet posted), the problem is that you were using `=` instead of `==`.

Take a look to this example:

first I generate test dataset

```
df <- data.frame("observed" = rep(c("observed", "predicted"), 3), 
                 "predicted" = "observed", 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

that looks like:

```
   observed predicted
1  observed  observed
2 predicted  observed
3  observed  observed
4 predicted  observed
5  observed  observed
6 predicted  observed
```

Then use `ifelse`

```
df$result <- ifelse(df$observed == df$predicted, "POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE")
```

and the result is

```
   observed predicted   result
1  observed  observed POSITIVE
2 predicted  observed NEGATIVE
3  observed  observed POSITIVE
4 predicted  observed NEGATIVE
5  observed  observed POSITIVE
6 predicted  observed NEGATIVE
```

Again, as @Soto pointed out, your problem was the type of data stored in your dataset. You have `factors` and it should be `characters`.

I took care of this issue adding `stringsAsFactors = F` when creating the dataset, this will also work with functions like `read.table` or `read.csv`.

Another option is using the solution @Soto suggested, that would be something like

```
df$observed <- as.character(df$observed)
df$predicted <- as.character(df$predicted)
```

before using the `ifelse` function.